# Generating source files with Maven outside the normal build process

Tags: maven

Our application includes some source files that are generated automatically, with application itself. This takes a lot of time, so this source generation is not included in the normal build process. Instead these files are included in VCS repository and are regenerated only when really needed (approx. once a month).

Basically, build process of the main program looks like this:

> compile files A, B, C, D and X

In Ant there was an additional target that was essentially

> compile files A, B and E, use output of resulting program to regenerate X

Then the resulting X was committed to VCS repository and was used in many successive builds of the main program. This target was not a part of the main build process and would only be run manually.

How would I approach this with Maven? I would preferably avoid submodules, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a separate Python script that runs the tool. Added the following bits of configuration to `pom.xml` to avoid building tools by default (the script makes sure to call `mvn compile -P build-tools` first):

```
<properties>
  <java.source.excludes>**/tools/**</java.source.excludes>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>${java.source.excludes}</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>build-tools</id>
    <properties>
      <!-- Has to be non-empty, or else Maven dies with an NPE... -->
      <java.source.excludes>we/include/everything/unless/you/named/a/file/like/this</java.source.excludes>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```